# how to check socket.io connection status using swift API

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, socket.io

I am using socket.io with my swift iOS app.  Occasionally my socket connection is dropped.

How can I check the status of the connection so that I may re-connect if it is not connected?  I couldn't find any commands for checking the status of the connection in the client API documents.

I'm using iOS 11 with swift 4.

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 4**:

```
    let socketConnectionStatus = socket.status

    switch socketConnectionStatus {
    case SocketIOStatus.connected:
        print("socket connected")
    case SocketIOStatus.connecting:
        print("socket connecting")
    case SocketIOStatus.disconnected:
        print("socket disconnected")
    case SocketIOStatus.notConnected:
        print("socket not connected")
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Searched through the code and found simple solution:

```
let socketConnectionStatus = SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.socket.status

switch socketConnectionStatus {
case SocketIOClientStatus.connected:
   print("socket connected")
case SocketIOClientStatus.connecting:
   print("socket connecting")
case SocketIOClientStatus.disconnected:
   print("socket disconnected")
case SocketIOClientStatus.notConnected:
   print("socket not connected")
}
```

Comment: is there any lisner to know when ever socket is disconnect ,lisner should call irrespective of  viewcontroller ,

Answer (score 0):

You can use it separately like the following ...

```
private var socket:SocketIOClient!



if socket.status == connecting || socket.status == connected {
    //socket is active 
    return 
}
```

or a better way is to use `active` parameter like follows...

```
func establishConnection(){
     if socket.status.active{
          return
      }
      socket.connect()
}
```